# Copying an array to a struct

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, copy

I have a problem. 
I have an array :

```
Uint8_t row [60];
```

and I have a struct too:

```
struct mystruct{
    uint8_t a:7;
    uint8_t b:1
    uint8_t data[0];
};
```

My program is in c++.

I want to copy the array in my struct. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Does `uint8_t data[0];` even compile? You should use a `std::vector<uint8_t>` instead.

Comment: How can I copy the array if I use vector?

Comment: You can use [`std::vector::assign()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/assign)

Answer (score 0):

Your struct does not have space for an array. The size of struct is 1 byte, since a & b share the same int.

`uint8_t data[0]` declares array of ints of size 0. So no space actually. 
You should change your struct to have space for an array, if you want to copy in into the struct.

Comment: I read about zero size array in structure in this site. I think its ok! Can I allocate memory to data[0] ?

Comment: No, you can't.  There is no space in the structure for the pointer. You declared zero sized array and compiler removed it as unnecessary. No memory allocated for it, even for the pointer. What you can do, it declare structure as
`struct mystruct{
    uint8_t a:7;
    uint8_t b:1
    uint8_t* data;
};`

and later allocate memory to data; In this way, data is the pointer to the array of ints, and compiler will save place for the pointer (but not to the data).
Dont forgeth that in this way allocated array will not reside together with the structure, but will be allocated in the heap.

Comment: or, on other hand you can do next
`mystruct * ptr = malloc(sizeof(mystruct) +sizeof(int*ARRAY_SIZE));`
Then you can use ptr->data[x], where 0<=x<ARRAY_SIZE;
This allocation will allocate memory for struct itself and array of ARRAY_SIZE;
But you cannot use zero sized array in declared on stack/ global struct;